# compiling C++ boost library for Sony NMOS implementation

Tags: c++, websocket, openssl

I'm compiling an open source software and in the process of satisfying the required dependencies I'm getting the following errors. The source is located here.

[Sony NMOS GIT Repository](https://github.com/sony/nmos-cpp)

The compilation errors appears to be related to C++ Boost and OpenSSL. It appears the c++ dependencies are not available. How can I compile c++ boost from source to resolve this issue? Second I will also have to compile OPENSSL and make the library available so the dependencies can be satisfied.

```
[root@nmos build]# cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="<Debug-or-Release>" -DWERROR:BOOL="0" -DBUILD_SAMPLES:BOOL="0" -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL="0"
-- Setting gcc options
-- websocketpp not found, using the embedded version
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:963 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1622 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2048 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/cpprest_find_boost.cmake:49 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:17 (cpprest_find_boost)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.0.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:412 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/cpprest_find_openssl.cmake:44 (find_package)
  cmake/cpprest_find_websocketpp.cmake:18 (cpprest_find_openssl)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:68 (cpprest_find_websocketpp)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/admin/cpprestsdk/Release/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/admin/cpprestsdk/Release/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to post questions like this as issues on the sony/nmos-cpp GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/sony/nmos-cpp/issues. Thanks!